# Change Text Labels to Fit New Size Paper

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, annotation

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

I am trying to create a new map based on a previous map which was in paper size Arch D. The new map is sized 11 by 17. I have fit the layers into the new maps, but I am unable to change my labels to fit on the new map.

My labels are annotations and right now are at the same scale as they were in the old map.

Comment: Are you using labels on your layer?  Or are you working with an annotation feature class that you have added as a layer?  Including a picture of the Source tab of your Layer Properties should clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues as you are. What I did was to save it as a new MXD file with name of the title with 11x17.

1. Rename the MXD file to name_11x17. Like for example, storm_11x17
2. In your Layout View, Use your “Select Elements" to drag around inside the map page and move them out of the Layout View.
3. Change the Page and Print Setup. Change the printer setup to find the printer that match with the 11x17. You can check on printing preview to see if they fit in the margin.
4. In the Page and Print Setup, in comments section, Under Paper, ensure you set to Tabloid (11x17) in the size group.
5. For the Map Page Size, I'd uncheck the Use the Printer Paper Size only if it can fit them inside the Printer Paper. You might need to manual them in that group to see if they fit inside it.
6. Go back to Step 2 and use the Select Elements to drag the Map page and drag them back in the Layout View and you may have to fix it. You may need to figure what the scale it is.
7. If you like what scale it is, you can then create a bookmark it should you need to come back and fix it again. Saves me a lot of my time.
8. Once you have settle down with this, you may need to fix the labels and Annotation. For the Annotation, you need to change the scale in ArcCatalog.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I fix the labels and Annotation? 

I do not know if my labels are officials labels or annotation, because I think those terms refer to specific types of features in ArcGIS, not just anything that is a label is regular usage of the word.

Comment: What scale are they in for the annotation ? The labets needs to be manually depends on what scale you are setting to ? Do I make myself clearly ?

Comment: My labels are all texts which I inserted manually. Do these texts have a scale? Are these labels annotations?

Comment: no, it affects them  if you set them to scale  for example, if you set your map at 1:24,000 they may be either too big or too small to read so it is hard to know which number you set to. Do you have the map up and what scale they are in ?

Comment: I still do not know how do solve my problem. How do I change the scale in ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fix the labels here is the link http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-about-displaying-labels.htm

To change the annotation to set the scale, first I would backup your existing annotation  for example Roadsannotion to RoadsannotationBU for Backup. You can copy and paste within the geodatabase and just rename it there.

This should help you to understand better how to deal with annotation"
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/aviation-charting/troubleshooting-size-and-specification-text-symbols-in-annotation.htm